# Filter click event of anchor tag

Tags: jquery, events

I have a div which will do some animation on click event.But I don't want to trigger the click event if I click on the anchor(< a href=' ' >) tags which lies on the same div.Is there any way to get the events are coming from anchor tag or not?
Here is the code snippet
https://gist.github.com/1694091

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('div').on('click', function(e) { 
        if(!$(e.target).is('a')) {
            alert('div clicked, but NOT an a!');
        }
    });
</script>
```

-- edit, sorry, too fast, didn't work, but this will! (tested)

Comment: :D Worked more than I expected

Comment: oops, I didn't check. I take my +1 :D

Comment: nooooo! give it back! ;) the snippet above does work btw, version _before_ edit didn't

Answer (score 2):

Stop propagation on anchor click,

```
$("a").click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
event.target == $('#anchorElement').get(0);
```

you can also do this:

```
$('#anchorElement')
 .click(
   function(e)
    {
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

anchor always have a name attribute, try this:

```
$("a").click(function(e) {
        if ($(this).hasAttr("name")) {

        }
    else{

    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Make 2 events - 1 for the div and 1 for the link, and use (as already suggested) stopPropagation to stop the link clicks also firing the div click event....

```
$(".stream-cell").on("click", function() {
    //  The div was clicked
});
$(".stream-cell a").on("click" function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    //  The link was clicked
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The Anchor tag has an onclick event just like anything else in the dom. I believe what you need is to have

```
 <a href='' onclick="javascript:return false;">Click ME!</a>
```